# Wicket: use a property of a CompoundPropertyModel twice in one Component

Tags: java, wicket

I have a POJO (of course this is a simplified example)

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Pojo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

That I want to use in a component twice, like so:

```
public class PojoPanel extends GenericPanel<Pojo> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PojoPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        add(new Label("property"));
        add(new MultiLineLabel("property"));
    }

}
```

with some markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <span wicket:id="property"></span><div wicket:id="property"></div>
</wicket:panel>
```

The parent Component has a `CompoundPropertyModel` Model, so the `"property"` ID will make sure the `property` of the Pojo is used.

This course will give problems; but I want to know if there is a nice shortcut, other than giving the `MultiLineLabel` a different markup-id and a Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The componentId really must be unique at the same level in component hierarchy. It means you can not use two components with the same id however you want to do it because of property resolving by compound's model type.

The most easy way how to solve your example is

```
public class PojoPanel extends GenericPanel<Pojo> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PojoPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        add(new Label("property"));
    }

    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();
        add(new MultiLineLabel("Xproperty", new PropertyModel(getDefaultModel(), "property")));
    }

}
```

with associated markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <span wicket:id="property"></span><div wicket:id="Xproperty"></div>
</wicket:panel>
```

Comment: yes, I thought of that solution myself also - though I must say that the `PropertyModel` looks like a nice shortcut to keep the model-initialization lazy (if that makes sense)

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right about that thing. Just PropertyModel allow you to call constructor without any idea about model of its parent, that could be sometime helpful. Good luck :-)